# HttpClient.PostAsync Unrecognized Response

Tags: c#, curl, dotnet-httpclient, dnx

If I run my web application on a Windows machine everything works out fine. When I run this application on a Linux (CentOS) machine I get the following exception when trying so send the Post request:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response. at System.Net.Http.CurlResponseHeaderReader.ReadHeader(String& headerName, String& headerValue) at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAgent.CurlReceiveHeadersCallback(IntPtr buffer, UInt64 size, UInt64 nitems, IntPtr context) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

This is the code that makes the post call:

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(ServiceConfiguration.SERVICE_URL);

    string sSOAPResponse = String.Empty;

    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", oRequest.Action);

    var content = new StringContent(oRequest.RequestMessage, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

    try
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.PostAsync(uri, content))
        {

            sSOAPResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            (...)
         }
```

I'm guessing that this is happening because of my headers definition. I've also tried using curl on the linux console to make a request and I got the response as expected. Am I doing something wrong with the header definitions?

CURL command example used with sucess ([Source](http://dasunhegoda.com/make-soap-request-command-line-curl/596/))

> curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: ACTION_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL" --data @FILE_NAME URL_OF_THE_SOAP_WEB_SERVICE_ENDPOINT

SOAP UI Request (RAW):

> POST http://xxx/xxx/xxx.php HTTP/1.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8 SOAPAction:
>   "http://xxx/xxx/xxx.php/userLogin" Content-Length: 488 Host: xxx
>   Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5

Comment: Seen this happen where either a web page comes back, or the encoding of the SOAP package is wrong. (SOAP says UTF8 but content is ANSI)

Comment: First of all thank you for your comment. Is there anyway I can check the invalid response? Well this is working fine on a Windows machine and also if I call it on command line with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I normally use SOAPUI to diagnose SOAP issues. You can check the raw soap message.

Comment: I've done that and everything seems in order (Edited Post with SOAPUI Raw Data)

Comment: Check the soap message contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well guys I've resolved this issue thanks to the DNX team on GitHub. I've creating a thread stating the issue on this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9201).

This is what I've done:

- I've got a PHP (NuSOAP) API running on my CentOS server. I sent in this command that showed the PHP headers info.

> [root@su soaptest]# curl -I http://application.com/api/service.php
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2016 01:21:20 GMT Server:
> Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: SOAPAction,Content-Type
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods :
> POST,GET,OPTIONS Connection: close Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=utf-8

The problem is the white space on (:) that is found in my main PHP API page (my case service.php)

> Access-Control-Allow-Methods : POST,GET,OPTIONS

Should be:

> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS

Aparentlly, (you can have a look at the entire issue on the link above) if you run the application on a Windows machine, this still reads the headers correctly (with or without the whitespace). They have now created an issue so this is also possible on a linux machine.

Thank you.